# Heroku postgres connection: "Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket"

Tags: sockets, heroku

I am setting up a new dev environment, followed the django setup tutorial and am having issues.  Here is what I get when I try to run syncdb

```
Running `python doccal/manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doccal/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__i
nit__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__i
nit__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/bas
e.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/bas
e.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/bas
e.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/com
mands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init_
_.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgre
sql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", lin
e 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or director
y
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have setup this same project before using the same steps and have never had a problem.  I did, a few weeks ago, get an email that Heroku was migrating away from shared databases and assume this is somehow involved.

Also, I did notice two NEW steps in the tutorial, namely, installing dj-database-url and adding these lines to settings.py

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

I have tried to run this both with and without these lines and get the same issue regardless.

Another post suggested the fix was to do this

```
heroku addons:add shared-database
```

Tried, get a message that shared-database is deprecated and to use heroku-postgresql, but that had no effect.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

config HOST as localhost like :

```
'HOST': 'localhost',
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest(not comprehensive but one to get you up and running as quick as possible) solution to this error is, in your settings.py file , in the part where you have set up database settings revert the settings to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

make migrations (i.e python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate)
push your changes to GitHub, in your Heroku account, create a new app then move to the setting portion of your new app, connect to GitHub and deploy from GitHub, the database resources will then be provisioned for you (i.e a PostgreSQL database will be created with the same schema and data as your local SQLite database).